# Error 500, I dont know why r&r, ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/runners/7/pagar?pago_ver=no&rutrun=7 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

In my JavaScript:

```
$("input#pago_ver").change(function() {
        var pagino=' ';
        if($(this).prop("checked") === false){
            pagito = 'no';
        }
        else{
            pagito = 'si';
        }
        var rut = ' '; 
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            rut = $(this).val();
        }
        var url = 'runners/'+rut+'/pagar';var url = 'runners/'+rut+'/pagar';
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET', // GET
                url: url, // url: 'runners/'+rut+'/pagar',
                data: { 'pago_ver' : pagito , 'rutrun' : rut},
                success: function(data){},
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        //alert("Status: " + textStatus + "\n -> valores: " + $("input#pago_ver").val()); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                    } 
            });
```

`rut`: is the `id` of a `runner`
pagito: verified is runner pay

router.rb

```
resources :runners do
    get "pagar", to: "runners#pagar"
  end
```

Controller:

```
def pagar
    @pagoo = params[:pago_ver]
    @rut = params[:rutrun]
    @run1 = Runner.where(id: @rut)
    if(@pagoo == 'si')
      #@run1.update_attribute(:pago, true)
      Runner.update(@rut, pago: true)
    else
      #@run1.update_attribute(:pago, false)
      Runner.update(@rut, pago: false)
    end 
  end
```

View:

```
<%if runner.pago==true %>
          <td><%=  check_box_tag(:pago_ver, runner.id, true) %></td>
          <%   else %>
          <td><%=  check_box_tag(:pago_ver, runner.id) %></td>
          <%  end %>
```

I have rack-cors but it still throws me that error.

Comment: from where you are setting pagito and rut variable?

Comment: edited sorry for that

Comment: you should provide server logs, not only console logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code defining url two times , I have removed one check it now

```
$("input#pago_ver").change(function() {
        var pagino=' ';
        if($(this).prop("checked") === false){
            pagito = 'no';
        }
        else{
            pagito = 'si';
        }
        var rut = ' '; 
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            rut = $(this).val();
        }
        var url = 'runners/'+rut+'/pagar';
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET', // GET
                url: url, // url: 'runners/'+rut+'/pagar',
                data: { 'pago_ver' : pagito , 'rutrun' : rut},
                success: function(data){},
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        //alert("Status: " + textStatus + "\n -> valores: " + $("input#pago_ver").val()); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                    } 
            });
```